# Adding National Grid Reference data from spreadsheet into QGIS

Tags: qgis, spreadsheet

I have been given some point data and loaded it against the relevant open street map. I'm looking to create a point shapefile based on the National Grid References (NGR) found within a spreadsheet.

If memory serves correctly, if I have the spreadsheet incorporated into my QGIS 3.12 project, I can access the relevant column containing the NGR to produce a points layer.

I'm not sure how to do either and struggling for the correct search terms to find the answer.

Comment: British National Grid? like NT 51422 13172 https://simon-m-mudd.github.io/QGIS_book/#_a_special_case_gps_coordinates_and_the_british_national_grid

Comment: Can you show us what these coordinates look like? Do they have a two-letter grid followed by an even number of digits? A short python function can convert the letters to an offset and add the numbers to get X-Y coordinates in the standard GB grid format. If your coordinates are all numbers then most of the hard work is done and you only need to split it as a string and that gets you X and Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert my coordinates outside Qgis, for example using the BGS coordinate converter, see https://www.bgs.ac.uk/technologies/web-services/coordinate-converter/.
Then you can load it directly as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

i found this on the OS website to convert National Grid ref to E&N or Lat&Longs
https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/coordinates

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/221030)